# Remember state of Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, gis, kml

I am displaying a map with placemarks and KML overlays. When a user clicks away, I want the state of the map to be remembered for when the user returns.

First question is: can I save the entire state of the map somehow; overlays and everything?

For now, I have been saving the lat/long and zoom and then replaying any KML overlays, but haven't even had any success with this. I save cookies on the bounds changed or window unload events, but the problem is with loading the saved values. the reason being the map loads asynchronously. I've tried using the map idle event, but it fires more than once. Seems to fire, run my code in the handler, then fire again when it's finished my code. Infinite loop? Anyway, the replaying of the KML overlay completely overrides whatever lat/long/zoom was specified.

So main question is: how do you restore a saved map with all its overlays?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Google Maps can save the state of the map, you have to do it by yourself.

You correctly used idle event to init the overlays. Idle event is triggered every time the map becomes idle after zooming or panning, so if you want one time listener for idle event (or any other event), you can do it this way:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions); 
var initListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
    // do your code here
    google.maps.event.removeListener(initListener);
});
```

If you want to preserve zoom and center of the map after loading kml, you have to use KmlLayer's option preserveViewport:

```
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer( myKml.kml, {preserveViewport: true});
```